# Yii2 ignores new Controller

Tags: routes, yii2

I am using Yii2 and trying to create a controller which renders a simple view in a subfolder.

- I have created with the gii Tool a new model based on a simple mysql table.
- After that I have created with the CRUD functionality a new controller

Here you can see my entered data from the gii >> CRUD generator:

[image]

everything looks good, but the controller will be ignored completely, because when I add any syntax error into my new controller code, I am getting no error message from Yii2 back.

And I think thats the reason, why my views wont be rendered by the controller.

So my concrete question is: Do I have to register a new controller somwhere in Yii2?

My views are strctured like this:

app/views/paxarten/index.php **or** app/views/paxarten/update.php

and my goal is to access them via this url structure

**www.myApplication.com/paxarten/index**

and my pretty URL structure is already enabled :)

Thx for any hints and any help!
**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\PaxArten;
use app\models\PaxArtenSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * PaxArtenController implements the CRUD actions for PaxArten model.
 */
class PaxArtenController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all PaxArten models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PaxArtenSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single PaxArten model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new PaxArten model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new PaxArten();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing PaxArten model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing PaxArten model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the PaxArten model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return PaxArten the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = PaxArten::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add dash `/pax-arten/index`. Read doc pls https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-class-naming

Answer (score -1):

oho wow >> I have found out the sometimes Yii2 got problems with 2 Uppercase Letters in Model names. Thats why i have renamed my initital mysql table without an underscore.

Then the gii CRUD generator will not add an upperCase into the ModelName

and then my controller Name was PaxartenController instead of PaxArtenController

works great now..

Hope this helps also other people, which having this issue.

Answer (score -2):

you should visit http://www.myApplication.com/pax-arten/index as SiZE said